# How Do I Rigorously Find The Limit Of The Following Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

How do I rigorously find the limit of the following sequence?

$$u_n = \sin\left(\dfrac{n^2+n+2}{(n-1)^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

The sine is a continuous function and its argument has a finite limit $L,$ therefore the limit of $u_n$ is $\sin L.$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n^2+n+2}{(n-1)^2}  = \frac{n^2+n+2}{n^2-2n+1} = \frac{1+1/n+2/n^2}{1-2/n+1/n^2} \rightarrow 1 (n\rightarrow \infty) $$

Thus, $$\sin\left(\frac{n^2+n+2}{(n-1)^2}\right) \rightarrow \sin(1) (n\to\infty)$$

Note that this works because $\sin(\cdot)$ is continuous, thus you can "move" the limit into the sin-function, i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(f(x)) = \sin(\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x))$$